# Change group ownership back to a single admin

Tags: site-template, modern-experience, office-365-groups, classic

I have a team site created with the classic template. This site is used by all in the company. I recently converted it to a group as well. I realized I don't want it as a group. Is there anyway to go back to a single admin on the site? I am afraid to delete the group - I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Microsoft ticket and ask them if they have some reverse functionality for this, once you converted site to group you are not able to convert it back.